# Unable to import packages depending on how and where scripts are started

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import, python-module

I'm trying to run some of my python scripts, but depending on from where and how I'm running them makes them fail with various errors and I'm unable to figure out how to correct my imports.

What is the proper way to check which packages are importable how and from where?
Right now I'm debugging the script and add imports - just this seems to me a rather random approach.

Here's my file structure:

```
Master
├── Testcases
│   ├── ATest.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── TestLinking.py
├── Handling
│   ├── Classes.py
│   ├── Functions.py
├── __init__.py
├── Database
│   ├── Debug.py
│   ├── ConnectionSupport.py
│   ├── Utils.py
│   ├── Initalisation.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Database.py
│   ├── Tests.py
│   ├── TKMenu.py
├── unittests.py
```

`Classes.py` contains several Classes: `Handling` is one of them.

**The working case**

I'm able to test everything with `unittests.py`. It's started from the parent folder and behaves as supposed. `Database.py` runs correctly, all imports work as they should. The `__init__.py` is quite simple, it only contains `from . import Handling`.

**`unittests.py`**:

```
import Database
from Handling import Classes, Functions
import unittest
import os

suite = unittest.TestSuite()
loader = unittest.TestLoader()

suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(Database.Tests))    

if __name__ == '__main__':       
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)
```

**Not working**

Now I'm in the folder Database. I'm starting `python3 Database.py` and I fail in the first line of code:

```
import Handling
```

with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Database.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Handling
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Handling'
```

Going back to the root-folder executing it from there gives the same result.

During the process I came up with similar errors, so I tried to add everything required in the `__init.py__`:

```
import Handling

import Testcases

from . import Debug
from . import ConnectionSupport
from . import Utils
from . import Database
from . import Tests
from . import Initalisation
from . import TKMenu
```

After some research I hoped I could solve the issue by importing the sibling-directory from my `Database.py`:

```
from .. import Handling
```

But this just gives me a more opaque error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Other options like `from .. Handling import Handling` give the same error.

**The case with mixed feelings**

`TKMenu.py` is a graphical interface for the `Database.py`. I'm currently using the following import to make it work (running TKMenu within its folder):

```
try:
    from Database.Database import Database #When called from the unittests we arrive here
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import Database #Opening it in its folder
```

It's working but I'm not satisfied about the way it does. Also it still fails as it arrives in Line 1 of `Database.py`. Yet running it from the Unittests is fine.

I would like to know how I'm able to find a proper solution to this problem. Is there a way to debug which packages are available from which point or can I import the parent-folder in a proper way?

Comment: Is `absolute imports` considerable ?

Comment: @hansolo - I have been trying using several variants of `from ..Handling import Handling`, all with the same result. If you got a solution that would work, I'm glad to try it

Comment: I wish I could figure out _how_ to at least check if the imports I'm trying to do are possible. For testing during the development seems to be a little much. The `__init__.py` I created for that exact purpose, but how can I pass the parents into the children?